# Searching oracle database using a "contains" query instead of an "exact match" query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I need to search my database which contains user information table. I know to get the result by searching with the query like the following

```
String query;
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(1024);
sb.append("select * from userinfo where uname=").append(key);
query=sb.toString();
```

But what I need to do is.

- If the key is `abc`
- Then I need to search for all data In the database which having the value `abc`
- For example
- My  database contains the data `abc`, `aba`, `gjabc` ,`abcxyz`,`hjjabcxyz`
- Then I need to retrieve the values `abc`, `gjabc`, `abcxyz`, `hjjabcxyz`
- Because all above values contains `abc` in common.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why exactly do you think that this is a servlet problem rather than a JPQL/SQL problem? A servlet is merely a HTTP request/response controller, not some DB interaction framework/language. You'd basically have had exactly the same problem when trying to achieve this using a plain vanilla Java class with a `main()` method.

Comment: @BalusC is of course right. However, as I interpret it, he actually can communicate with the database. The question would need some editing.

Comment: I removed the irrelevant tags anyway. Note that your original code has a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) [attack](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) hole.

Comment: @BalusC That I know. But why I performing this task with servlet is, For me it is easy to maintain... I'm happy to accept suggestions from you and all I'm a student... thanks...

Comment: It's in the end just Java/JDBC code. The class/context wherein you execute it is irrelevant to the concrete problem/question. It's importable/reusable everywhere, a servlet, a webservice, a swing app, etc..etc..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using pure SQL you should use like surrounded with "%". Your query will then return all rows where uname contains "abc". Your query needs to look like this:

```
select * from userinfo where uname like '%key%'
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it won't use indexes, unlike a free-text index.

Comment: @Ben But maybe it is good enough for james? :) Would be nice to see your solution though, I'm by no means a database expert.

Comment: @Magnus Tengdahl It is not working form me because I'm using Oracle database. it produces the error `invalid character` Tell me how to archive this in `Oracle` database..

Comment: It works with Oracle. I recommend you to carefully read the error message and find out which character that is invalid.

Comment: I'm at work Magnus, little time, but the documentation for full-text indexing is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/csql.htm#i997737). @James, this is correct Oracle syntax; you must be implementing it incorrectly in Java...

Answer (score 2):

Correct implementation would use a PreparedStatement.

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from userinfo where uname like ?");
ps.setString(1, key);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

of course this misses all error checking and plumbing code :)

Comment: It's also missing the `%`s that should surround the `key` value.